# Which is the PSD size for supporting normal and large screen size?

Tags: android, layout, size, screen, psd

I am developing an Android App which has to support only normal and large size devices and all densities. I read the Android documents "Support Multiple Screen Size", but I am a little bit confused... I understand how to provide different resources for different densities, but not which is the baseline resolution to use. HVGA seems to be old.

My graphic designer wants to know how to set the .PSD size in order to export graphics at the right dimension for supporting normal and large screen size.

Assuming that he works with mdpi (~160dpi)and then he will export the images in ldpi and hdpi with the appropriate scale factor, the question is: which resolution should have the PSD?

What do you suggest me to tell him? I don't know how is the best practice to follow.

Comment: Even I am looking for this answer I got answer from http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/advanced_web_design.asp just visit there at least once bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the size of the largest resolution you will support. Then downscale from there for lower densities (or let the OS handle the rescaling, but I think your designer would prefer to rescale himself. There's no one exact resolution, as there are a variety of resolutions and aspect ratios to support. Just keep any relevant details in the image away from the far edges, size for a particular aspect ratio (or 2) something like 16:9 or 4:3 and just work your way down from there.